# relationship between modulation index and carrier-suppressed condition in fm

Tags: modulation, frequency-modulation

What is the relationship between modulation index and carrier-suppressed condition in FM.

What should the modulation index be when the carrier is suppressed in FM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this fills whole chapters of some large textbooks[1], but to summarize a *lengthy* discussion involving Bessel functions of the first kind, the carrier component vanishes for `M=2.405, 5.520, 8.653, 11.79, 14.93, ...` Mathematically, these are the zeros of J<sub>0</sub>(M).

[1]: Cook & Liff, *Frequency Modulation Receivers,* Prentice Hall, 1968, Fig 1-19, but you will find the same diagram in numerous texts.